# Query Error, cant display correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I have an error in my query, I tried to display Date, Data name (which is POS and Non-POS) and number of data.

Desired output:

```
02/20/2014, POS, 40
02/20/2014, Non-POS, 15
```

Query:

```
SELECT To_char(D.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
FROM   owner_dwh.dc_date d 
       left join (SELECT Count(CASE 
                                 WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                      'POS-generic') 
                                                                    THEN 1 
                                 ELSE NULL 
                               END) --POS 
                         ||',' 
                         ||Count(CASE 
                                   WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper 
                                        ( 
                                        'hcphuser') THEN 
                                   1 
                                   ELSE NULL 
                                 END) --USER 
                  FROM   app_account.otrs_ticket t 
                  WHERE  Trunc(t.create_time, 'DAY') BETWEEN 
                         SYSDATE - 119 AND SYSDATE - 1 
                  GROUP  BY Trunc(t.create_time, 'DAY')) 
              ON d.dtime_day = t.create_time 
       left join(SELECT Count(CASE 
                                WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                     'POS') 
                                                                    THEN 1 
                                ELSE NULL 
                              END) --POS 
                        ||',' 
                        ||Count(CASE 
                                  WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                       'user') 
                                THEN 1 
                                  ELSE NULL 
                                END) --USER 
                 FROM   app_account.otrs_ticket t 
                 WHERE  Trunc(t.close_time, 'DAY') BETWEEN SYSDATE - 119 AND 
                                                           SYSDATE - 1 
                 GROUP  BY Trunc(t.close_time, 'DAY')) 
              ON d.dtime_day = t.close_time 
WHERE  t.queue_id NOT IN ( 63, 61, 69, 59, 
                           58, 60, 56, 64, 
                           65, 23, 67, 68, 57 );
```

My error:

```
 ORA-00904: "T"."CREATE_TIME": invalid identifier
 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Data in DTIME_DAY (OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE) is like this:

```
  02/12/2014
  02/13/2014
  02/14/2014
```

While in App_account.otrs.ticket

create_time and close_time contains date of open and close ticket
TICKET_CUSTOMER_USER_ID contains POS-generic and user (its like a category)

Please help me and correct my query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not too sure with oracle but it looks like you haven't aliases your joins.

Comment: Your error message and your query don't match - you don't have create_time in your query. Please show the *real* query you're running and the *real* error message you're getting.

Comment: that's the real error that i got when i run that query. Sorry im just only beginner in oracle

Comment: Is *OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE* the name of the table or column? Looks strange. And an error says that there is no column CREATE_TIME in APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET table. Provide your talbe structure.

Comment: It looks for CREATE_TIME in OTRS_TICKET table. You need to remove the alias.

Comment: I already provide some data

Comment: why should i remove the alias @Kuzgun?

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the alias, outside the brackets:

```
SELECT To_char(D.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
FROM   (owner_dwh.dc_date d 
        left join (SELECT Count(CASE 
                                  WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                       'POS-generic') 
                                                                      THEN 1 
                                  ELSE NULL 
                                END) --POS 
                          ||',' 
                          ||Count(CASE 
                                    WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = 
                                         Upper( 
                                         'hcphuser') THEN 
                                    1 
                                    ELSE NULL 
                                  END), --USER
                          t.create_time -- !!!of course, did not think about returning the field from the subquery!!!
                   FROM   app_account.otrs_ticket t 
                   WHERE  Trunc(t.create_time, 'DAY') BETWEEN 
                          SYSDATE - 119 AND SYSDATE - 1 
                          AND t.queue_id NOT IN ( 63, 61, 69, 59, 
                                                  58, 60, 56, 64, 
                                                  65, 23, 67, 68, 57 ) 
                   GROUP  BY Trunc(t.create_time, 'DAY')) t 
               ON d.dtime_day = t.create_time) 
       left join(SELECT Count(CASE 
                                WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                     'POS') 
                                                                      THEN 1 
                                ELSE NULL 
                              END) --POS 
                        ||',' 
                        ||Count(CASE 
                                  WHEN Upper(t.ticket_customer_user_id) = Upper( 
                                       'user') 
                                THEN 1 
                                  ELSE NULL 
                                END), --USER
                        t.close_time -- return from subquery!!!!
                 FROM   app_account.otrs_ticket t 
                 WHERE  Trunc(t.close_time, 'DAY') BETWEEN SYSDATE - 119 AND 
                                                           SYSDATE - 1 
                        AND t.queue_id NOT IN ( 63, 61, 69, 59, 
                                                58, 60, 56, 64, 
                                                65, 23, 67, 68, 57 ) 
                 GROUP  BY Trunc(t.close_time, 'DAY')) u 
              ON d.dtime_day = u.close_time --you can not use t twice for the joins!!!
```

This is all I could gather from your query...

Comment: there's still an erro : ORA-00904: "T"."CREATE_TIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: I edited the query, you must - of course - return the field from the subquery... your query is just hard to interpret... :)

Comment: sorry. there's still an error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: how can i display the result of left join? i mean the total count of 'POS' and 'user'? with date?